# Reducing space between table rows. \arrayrowstretch and \extrarowheight not working

Tags: tables

How do I decrease the space between the rows in the table shown? I was unable to do so using `\arrayrowstretch` and `\extrarowheight`. Here is the code I used:

```
\newcommand*{\cvpressentry}[4]{
  {\setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}}
  {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}}
  \def\arraystretch{0.7}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}L{1.5cm} L{14.5cm}}    
           \publdatestyle{#1} & \publpubtitlestyle{#2}  \publauthorstyle{#3} \publvenuestyle{\href{#4}{\faExternalLink}}
  \end{tabular*}
```

[image: table with row borders showing the space between the rows]

The table `\hline`s are added for clarity of the issue.

UPDATE: Based on the Sveinung's observation of separate tabular environments, I removed it and made it into a single tabular environment and it solved the problem.

Comment: Could you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your code that each text line is a separate tabular. The space between tabulars may be reduced by different means, but the simplest may be to set a negative space before the tabular:

```
\newcommand*{\cvpressentry}[4]{
  {\setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}}
  {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}}
  \def\arraystretch{0.7}
  \vspace{-10pt}              %% <- test with different values
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}L{1.5cm} L{14.5cm}}    
           \publdatestyle{#1} & \publpubtitlestyle{#2}  \publauthorstyle{#3} \publvenuestyle{\href{#4}{\faExternalLink}}
  \end{tabular*}
```

NB! Not tested (you have not provide a compilable MWE).